# How to handle formula with a variable name with % in it when using eval()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, eval

I want to use python's `eval()` function to evaluate a formula, the formula is

```
formula = 'x% + y% + z'
```

the `x%` and `y%` are valid column name from a `DataFrame`, but when calling the `eval()`, it treat the `%` as the modulo operator, so how can I force python to treat it as variable name `x%` and `y%`?

Comment: *"I want to use python's eval()"* why? `df['x%'] + df['y%'] + z`

Comment: What do you want to *eval* them to (what *foumula* should be)? They only have meaning in the *df*, not in your code. Also *eval* works for **pure *Python* code**, and its usage it's discouraged. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval.

Comment: (1) "eval" is dangerous as it can execute arbitrary code. (2) You can't (without editing and recompiling Python's code). You could e. g. do some search and replace on the string to use allowed variable names instead.

Comment: Do you want to use [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas-eval) ?

Comment: If `x% + y% + z` itself is invalid Python code, why do you think `eval()` wouldn't also treat it as invalid? If you wanted it to work, you'd have to do it like `df['x%'] + df['y%'] + z`, but then why use an `eval` when you could just write the literal code? Maybe you have a use case this makes sense for but your question did not make this clear.

Comment: well, i should rephase my question, i current use df.pivot_table(columns='variable_name').stack(0).eval(formula).unstack() to evaluate a formula, where x% and y% and z are just values in variable_name column, this code doesn't work when there's % in that column value, eval() treat it as a module operation. I can bypass this by replace the % in the variable_name colume, but think if there's a simple way to still eval() the formula by treating % as part of colume name. hope this can make the question a bit clearer